# How to mock an abstract class in Jasmine unit test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I've never used Jasmine before and I have a complicated http flow to test.
I am using Angular 16.

A service calls an Abstract Class to do all the HTTP requests.

So to test DataService.getData() , is it as simple as mocking abstractService.get() using SpyOn() ? How would I do it?

**Service to Unit Test:**

```
import { AbstractService } from '@services/http.abstract_service';

export class DataService {

    constructor( private abstractService: AbstractService ){ }
    
    getData(): Observable<HttpResponse> {

            const url = `http://example.com/Data`;

            const response = this.abstractService.get(url);

            return response;
            
        }
}
```

**The Abstract Class:**

```
export abstract class AbstractService {
    public abstract get(url: string): Observable<any>;
}
```

**The service extending the abstract class:**

```
export class HttpService extends AbstractService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){ 
        super();
    }
    
    get(url: string): Observable<HttpResponse> {
    
        return this.http.get(url).pipe(
            map((res: any) => {

                let responseBody = res?.body;
                let result: HttpResponse;

                result = { 
                    status: res.status, 
                    data: responseBody.data,
                    success: responseBody.success, 
                    message: responseBody.message
                });
    
    }
    
}
```

**My HttpResponse model:**

```
export class HttpResponse {
    status: number | undefined;
    data: any;
    success: boolean | undefined;
    message: string | undefined;
}
```

Comment: Check this out: https://testing-angular.com/testing-components-depending-on-services/#testing-components-depending-on-services (It will show you how to mock services) and then check this out https://testing-angular.com/testing-services/#testing-services (testing services).